# Update my database using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, symfony

I am trying to understand the CRUD in Eloquent, but I have some problems right here.

my first mistake that I didn't use the default controller index, create, store,...

I made my own names.

OK let me show my controller and routes

**Routes**

```
Route::get('edit-about', array('before' => 'admin_auth', 'uses' => 'PagesController@updateAbout', 'as'=>'edit-about'));
Route::put('edit-content', array('before' => 'admin_auth', 'uses' => 'PagesController@editAboutContent'));
```

**Controller**

```
public function updateAbout()
    {
        $text_area = Text_area::find(1);
        return View::make('admin.editText.about', compact('text_area'));
    }

    public function editAboutContent()
    {
        $id = Input::get('id');
        Text_area::updated($id, array(
            'titleArabic' => Input::get('title'),
            'contentArabic' => Input::get('content')
        ));
        return Redirect::to('edit-about');
    }
```

now display the first routes is OK `edit-about` but coming to the second route

`Route::put('edit-content', array('before' => 'admin_auth', 'uses' => 'PagesController@editAboutContent'));`

I get

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException

as the route is not there.

**Edit**

here is my Form header

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'edit-content', 'PUT')) }}
```

Comment: can you please post html of your form.
My suggestion is that you send your form as POST rather than PUT.

Comment: @xAoc I update my question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this.

```
Form::open(array('url'=>'edit-content',  'method' => 'PUT'))
```

You simply forget the key `method` :)

Comment: I have to say it's working as redirecting to the edit page so this solved the routes problem, but it didn't do the update

Comment: I will make you a tip `Text_area::updated` this is not correct. I recommend you read documentation one more time more carefully. Cheers!